# How to DllImport char*

Tags: c#, c++, interop, dllimport

I have a c++ function like this:

**myExport.h**

```
extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) const int Run(char *input, char *output, int *length); }
```

**myExport.cpp**

```
const int Run(char *input, char *output, int *length) {

    std::ostringstream value;
    value
        << "FOO" << "|"
        << "BAR" << "|";

    auto str = value.str();

    auto i = stdext::checked_array_iterator<char*>(output, str.length());
    std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), i);
    output[str.length()] = '\0';

    return 1;
}
```

And in C# I have:

**myImport.cs**

```
[DllImport("MyExport.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int Run(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string input,
    StringBuilder output,
    ref int length);

public static string Execute(string input)
{
    var length = 1024;
    var output = new StringBuilder(1024);
    var result = Run(input, output, ref length);
    return output.ToString();
}
```

However, the output buffer is always empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you confirm that your C++ function works correctly by running a test against another C or C++ application?  You didn't specify which side of the fence is not working, the DLL side or the C# side.

Comment: A character in c++ is one byte wide while a character in c# is one/two characters wide depending on encoding.  MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr) is correct for input but also should be for output.  Stringbuilder won't work.

Comment: Try with `[Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]` before the output parameter

Comment: Also, your C++ function doesn't set the `length` argument and it doesn't respect the `length` sent by the client.  It just goes and copies the string into the buffer regardless of what the client specified.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The function works when called from c++

Comment: @bob1024 Just tried, same result

Comment: @ConditionRacer I dug this up from a very old C# interface I have.  Give this a try for the third parameter: `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]System.Text.StringBuilder` as the output parameter.  Also, my other comment still stands -- your C++ function doesn't use the `length` parameter in any way and will cause a buffer overwrite if the client wants less characters copied than the actual number of characters in the string.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I get the same result with that attribute. Agreed as far as the length comment, I havent gotten that far yet, just trying to get the damn thing to return a string first :)

Comment: @ConditionRacer I have used `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]System.Text.StringBuilder` with no issues between C# and an exported C DLL function that fills in a char buffer.  How are you determining that the function is not working and the string is empty?  Maybe the `ToString` is throwing you off track? The bytes couldn't just simply disappear if you really did copy them into the buffer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Whoops, looks like I was doing something while building the return string in the c++ function that was inserting a null terminator at the front of the string. However, your suggestion was also needed to make it work. I'll mark your suggestion as correct if you submit it as an answer.

Comment: @ConditionRacer Which suggestion?  I made two, 1) the marshalling change and 2) the C++ change to respect the length argument.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Marshalling change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the type is `char *` for the second parameter, and the DLL function will fill in the buffer that's passed, the C# declaration should be as follows:

`[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]System.Text.StringBuilder output`

Comment: That's exactly how it is declared in the question. This cannot change a thing.